# Error when importing psycopg2 library

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to import the psycopg2 library in Rodeo but am getting an error.

- psycopg2 version 2.6.2
- Python version 3.5

Error:

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-bd284aa2cf56> in <module>()
----> 1 import psycopg2

/Users/chrisstroud/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.2-py3.5-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/__init__.py in <module>()
 48 # Import the DBAPI-2.0 stuff into top-level module.
 49 
---> 50 from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
 51 
 52 from psycopg2._psycopg import Binary, Date, Time, Timestamp

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/chrisstroud/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.2-py3.5-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/chrisstroud/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2-2.6.2-py3.5-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to install psycopg2 using ***pip***:

> pip install psycopg2

If you are on linux or Mac, you have to use ***sudo*** to give root permission.

After that, just import the library using:

> import 'psycopg2'

If it doesn't work, you should to put the library folder in your project folder to work.